# LDAP query to get Active Directory default folders

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am looking for a query to get default containers/folder for ex:Builtin, Users , Computer etc.

any Idea?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I' don't understand why you want this query but here it is:

```
ldifde -f contaiers.LDIF -d "dc=dom,dc=fr" -r (objectclass=container) -p onelevel -l cn
```

`-r (objectclass=container)` is the LDAP filter
`-l cn` means that I just want to retreive one attribute (CN)
`-p onelevel` means that I'am just fing in one level under the nod where begin the search (`-d "dc=dom,dc=fr"`)

It gives :

```
dn: CN=Computers,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: Computers

dn: CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: ForeignSecurityPrincipals

dn: CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: Managed Service Accounts

dn: CN=Program Data,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: Program Data

dn: CN=System,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: System

dn: CN=Users,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: Users
```

If you just want to see those you normaly view just change the filter to "`-r (&(objectclass=container)(showInAdvancedViewOnly=FALSE))`", you will receive :

```
dn: CN=Computers,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: Computers

dn: CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: ForeignSecurityPrincipals

dn: CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: Managed Service Accounts

dn: CN=Users,DC=dom,DC=fr
changetype: add
cn: Users
```

JP

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the [well-known security principals](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330) ?

Those well-known principals (groups and users) have specific, pre-defined SID's which you can use to find them in the directory.